Passivate one channel on a dual band chip antenna 2.4GHz / 5GHz
I'm making a dual band chip antenna design. For 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz
The antenna is this one: ANT162442DT-2001A2 from TDK
My problem: I'm using an esp32-c3 with 2.4GHz support... no 5GHz support... so I have to do something with the 5GHz radiator pin... but I'm not sure what to do...
This is because if I left the 5GHz pin unconnected, I'll break the isolation of that little isle of GND (the one that enters from the long side of the antenna). This isolated GND zone is connected to the rest of the circuit trough "Mt Common" (SMD inductor). In the evaluation board this isolation keeps going until the edge of the PCB...
If I just leave the 5GHz radiator pin unconnected, I'm going to loose this isolation with a direct contact with GND... and I'm pretty sure that i'm going to mess the whole thing
//------------------------------------//
My biggest reason to use this dual band antenna instead of a single band (2.4GHz) is that i'm waiting for the ESP32-C5 to come out (this one has dual band support) and I want to have some experience with dual band chip antennas before it comes out.
It's also very cheap... cheaper than a single band antenna for it's size (0603). Also is the one with most of the available stock on JLCPCB (JLC part number: C531339)
//------------------------------------//
I'm pretty new with the antenna field... I'm pretty sure that I'm going to buy a nanoVNA or something... Your help will be highly appreciated, best regards, Cristian
//------------------------------------//
Here you can see the keep out area (non metal area) (gray area)




Connect both sides of the antenna as shown. You do not have to use the 5GHz band. What is and where do you see an "isolated ground"? Looks like the "Mt Common" component is used for matching to 50 Ohm. Why does the 2.4GHz side of the antenna need vias? Where do the vias go?
